# cancancan manage a relationship Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancancan

I am running into an issue with the cancancan gem for rails

```
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'
```

I have four models: User, Company, Locations, Groups

User: Belongs to Company
Company: Has many Locations
Location: Belongs to company
Group: Belongs to Location

In the abilities model I have this:

```
can :manage, Group, :location => {:id => user.company.locations.map{|l| l.id}}
```

When creating a new group I am denied (don't have access)

I am looking for the correct way to allow a User to create a group with one of the companies location id's (NOTE: Without cancancan on this all works and all ID's are related and so on).

Answer (score 1):

To make sure I'm understanding your question completely...

You're looking for a way to limit a User's ability to manage Groups based on the locations of the Company that User belongs to?

Assuming I've got that correct, I would recommend using [#pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck):

```ruby
can :manage, Group, location_id: user.company.locations.pluck(:id)
```

This collects all the `:id`'s on a User's Company's Locations, and ensures a User can only manage Groups that have a :location_id contained within that collection.

Functionally, this is identical to what you've done, but is more efficient in two ways:

1. It doesn't involve any unnecessary Ruby logic
2. Using #pluck only queries the `:id` on a location, as opposed to the entire location *and* all its attributes

Generally speaking, whenever you're accessing your database in Rails, you're better off doing so entirely with ActiveRecord methods. This will help prevent you from wasting time querying for extra information you don't need, and eliminate the extra overhead of using Ruby to re-structure your data.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion on using pluck is just what I was looking for! However I am still not able to create a Group. When try to create, it shows me that I do not have access to that resource.

Comment: Hmm... Just to double-check, you're trying to create a group for a location that belongs to a company to which your user account belongs, right? 

Because if cancancan is set up correctly, you would only be able to create a group if it had a location_id that existed in your company's collection of locations. If the group you try to create doesn't have the requisite location_id, it *should* deny you.

Comment: Correct, I have included more details below:

    def group_params
        params.require(:group).permit(:name, :location_id)
    end


Create Method:
    @group.create(group_params).save


Params sent in the dev log:
    `"group"=>{"name"=>"Test"}, "button"=>"", "location_id"=>"1"}`

Comment: This is gonna be tricky for me to troubleshoot without seeing the rest of your project. Have you verified that the `company_id` on your User and the `company_id` on the Location with id = 1 are the same? If they *are*, then I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Yes, I only have one user one company and one location. So all ID's are good... I am not sure whats going on!